# Don't know how to use a hash table to solve a problem

Tags: c, data-structures, hashtable

I have to solve the following problem (in C) using a hash table (I assume using a hash table since we are studying hash tables right now):

The first line of the input has 2 numbers : **n**, **m**

Next, we input **n** lines with **m** numbers. (so a **n*m** matrix)
We have to go from the top left corner to the bottom right corner (only by moving south or east). Each cell that we cross either adds the number in the cell to a variable "**s**" or decreases it. So if we traverse a cell with -5 we will have **s-5** , if we traverse a cell with +3 we will have **s+3**. At the beginning, **s** is the number in the top left corner, which is always >0. Another rule is that we cannot traverse a cell with the number 0. Also, every time we leave a cell we must subtract 1, so every time we leave a cell we will have **s-1**.
The output must be the maximum **s** that can be obtained after reaching the bottom right corner.
Here is an example of input/output:

[image]

It is guaranteed that there is at least one path to the bottom right corner which will give in the end an **s** equal to at least 1, so if in the end **s** is negative the path is guaranteed to be wrong.

I am having a really hard time solving this (especially using a hash table) so any help is much appreciated. Also, is there any other more efficient way of solving it?

Comment: This doesn't seem like an exercise that needs a hash table. It seems like it should just be arrays.

Comment: Is this an efficient way of solving it when n and m get big? @Barmar

Comment: Unless there are lots of `0` entries that could be omitted from a hash table, it will be more efficient.

Comment: If your assessment is correct, it's sounds like it's trying to railroad you into implementing it as a recursive function that memoizes its results in a hashtable. There's no benefit to a hashtable over a 2d array in this specific instance though.

Comment: A hash table can be more memory efficient than a 2d array if there are a lot of zeros.

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out how in your example matrix, how the output is `2`.  If your starting sum is 10, then there are plenty of ways to reach the bottom right corner with a cumulative cost of more than 2.

Comment: @selbie You may have missed the "every time we leave a cell we will have s-1" part. I guess the path would be 10-1 -6-1 +2-1 -1-1 +1-1 +3-1 -1 = 2.

Comment: Or, since exactly 6 moves will be needed to reach the end, regardless of the path taken, you could simply start with `10 - 6`. And then the answer is 4-6+2-1+1+3-1=2. The only reason for subtracting 1 at each move would be if there was a restriction that the partial sums can't be negative on a valid path (e.g. if positive numbers are food gained, negative are food lost, and movement requires one food). The restriction that partial sums must not be negative wasn't stated in the problem description, so the subtract-one-at-each-move requirement is rather silly.

Comment: @user3386109 IIUC, the path is not restricted to down and right. One some grids we may want to take up and left steps, leading to paths longer than `n+m-2`. The subtract-on-at each-move punishes these long paths.

Comment: @user58697 *"(only by moving south or east)."*

Comment: A hard time and you have no code to show? How hard that can be?  Please, show code, or it will be very difficult to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mark mentioned that this is Dynamic Programming problem. So this problem has nothing to do with hash table. Now, since Mark's answer was little tough to understand, I will try to explain my solution.
The given problem is similar to standard matrix path optimisation problem with two interesting twists.

1. The solution path cannot contain `0 valued cells`.
2. Above point is also a standard problem. But here's the twist. Since cells has integer values. It will be difficult to differentiate between the original `0 valued cells` with the ones in the intermediate `dp` matrix as result of previous addition and subtraction operations.

So to solve above problem we need to store the indices of original `0 valued cells` separately. Easiest way is to create another reference matrix and mark the `0 valued cells`.

Now, we apply straightforward dynamic programming technique.

1. `dp[i][j]= dp[i][j] + max(dp[i-1][j],dp[i][j-1]) - 1;`
2. `if (zeroed[i][j] == 1)` i.e  is a `0 valued cell` then ignore this cell.
3. `if (zeroed[i-1][j] == 1)`  then ignore addition with top cell.
4. `if (zeroed[i][j-1] == 1)` then ignore addition with left cell.
5. `dp[row-1][col-1]` is optimised answer.

This is how we solve this problem. If you still find it difficult then you need to study dynamic programming.
Program code :

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int zeroed[50][50]; //for reference of 0 valued cells
int main(){
        int dp[50][50];
        int row,col,value;
        cin>>row>>col;
        /*=========initializing matrix========*/
        for(int i=0;i<row;i++){
                for(int j=0;j<col;j++){

                        cin>>value;
                        dp[i][j]=value;
                        if(value == 0){
                                zeroed[i][j]=1; //marking 0 valued cell
                        }

                }
        }

        /*==========applying dynamic programming=====*/
        for(int i=0;i<row;i++){
                for(int j=0;j<col;j++){
                        if(zeroed[i][j]== 1){
                                continue; //just ignore this cells
                        }
                        if(i>0 && j>0){
                                if(zeroed[i-1][j] !=1 && zeroed[i][j-1]!=1){
                                        dp[i][j]+=max(dp[i-1][j],dp[i][j-1]) - 1;
                                }else if(zeroed[i-1][j]!=1){
                                        dp[i][j]+= dp[i-1][j] - 1;
                                }else if(zeroed[i][j-1]!=1){
                                        dp[i][j]+=dp[i][j-1] - 1;
                                }
                                //ignore other cases

                        }else if(i>0){
                                if(zeroed[i-1][j]!=1){
                                        dp[i][j]+=dp[i-1][j] - 1;
                                }
                                //ignore other cases
                        }else if(j>0){
                                if(zeroed[i][j-1]!=1){

                                        dp[i][j]+=dp[i][j-1] - 1;
                                }
                                //ignore other cases
                        }
                }
        }
        cout<<dp[row-1][col-1];//max s 
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Forgot that you asked for c program. But you can easily replace c++ inputs with c syntax.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a pretty straightforward dynamic programming problem.

Let the top-left corner be given indices `(0, 0)` and the bottom-right `(n - 1, m - 1)`, and let `arr[i][j]` be the number in the `(i, j)` position. Then for all `i, j` such that `0 <= i < n` and `0 <= j < m`, define `f(i, j)` to be the largest possible `s` for getting from position `(0, 0)` to position `(i, j)`, and `-1` if this is not possible.

Define `combine(previousS, valueInCell)` to be `INT_MIN` if `previousS = INT_MIN` or `valueInCell = 0`, and `previousS + valueInCell - 1` otherwise.

Then we see the following is true:

`f(0, 0) = arr[0, 0]`
`f(i, 0) = combine(f(i - 1, 0), arr[i][0])` for all `1 <= i < n`
`f(j, 0) = combine(f(j - 1, 0), arr[0][j])` for all `1 <= j < m`
`f(i, j) = combine(max(f(i - 1, j), f(i, j - 1)), arr[i][j])` for all `1 <= i < n` and `1 <= j < m`

In particular, we're looking for `f(n - 1, m - 1)`.

Now this is a recursive algorithm, but recursion will be very inefficient because we can make up to 2 recursive calls each time. So we instead will define an array `f[i][j]` to hold the values of `f`.

```c
int combine(int previous_s, int value_in_cell) {
    return previous_s == INT_MIN || value_in_cell == 0 ? INT_MIN : previous_s + value_in_cell - 1;
}

int max(int i, int j) {
    return i > j ? i : j;
}

int computeS(int n, int m, int** arr) {
    int** const f = malloc(n * sizeof *f);
    int** const end_f = f + n;
    for(int** j = f; j < end_f; j++) {
        *j = malloc(m * sizeof **j);
    }
    f[0][0] = arr[0][0];
    for(int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        f[i][0] = combine(f[i - 1][0], arr[i][0]);
    }
    for(int j = 1; j < m; j++) {
        f[0][j] = combine(f[0][j - 1], arr[0][j]);
    }
    for(int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        for(int j = 1; j < m; j++) {
            f[i][j] = combine(max(f[i - 1][j], f[i][j - 1]), arr[i][j]);
        }
    }
    int const ret_val = f[n - 1][m - 1];
    for(int** j = f; j < end_f; j++) {
        free(*j);
    }
    free(f);
    return ret_val;
}
```

As you can see, no hash table required.

The code for doing the I/O:

```c
int main() {
    int n, m;
    scanf("%d%d", &n, &m);
    int** const arr = malloc(n * sizeof *arr);
    int** const end_arr = arr + n;
    for(int** j = arr; j < end_arr; j++) {
        *j = malloc(m * sizeof **j);
        for(int* k = *j; k < *j + m; k++) {
            scanf("%d", k);
        }
    }
    
    printf("%d\n", computeS(n, m, arr));
    
    for(int**j = arr; j < end_arr; j++) {
        free(*j);
    }
    free(arr);
    
    return 0;
}
```